# Ansible Obtain thumbprint hash from local machine

Tags: ansible, ssl-certificate

Im trying to obtain the thumbprint from a localmachine's cert store so I can then use the variable of the hash to pass the thumbprint into an `ssl_bindings` task. So far I have this, but it returns a lot of data. Should I filter the data out or is there an easier way to get the thumbprint from an existing store? I've seen this done with powershell so I may just go that route if I cant figure this out.

```
    - name: Obtain information about LocalMachines Cert Store
      community.windows.win_certificate_info:
        store_location: LocalMachine
      register: cert
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this. If anyone knows how to use the native ansible module to get the hash, that would be cool.

```
    - name: Run powershell one-liner to get the thumbprint hash
      ansible.windows.win_powershell:
        script: |
         (Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My  | where-object { $_.Subject -like "*$hostname*" } | Select-Object -Last 1).Thumbprint
      register: hash

    - name: Add an HTTPS binding to the website using the hash
      win_iis_webbinding:
        name: "{{ iis_site }}"
        protocol: https
        port: 443
        certificate_hash: "{{ hash.output[0] }}"
        state: present
```